# Togglebutton not turning off when other Togglebutton is clicked

Tags: android, xml

I have 3 toggle buttons. Only one is allowed to be on at a time. Can anyone tell me why the other two toggle buttons don't turn off if the third button is pressed.

MusicPlayerActivity.java

```
  package com.example.musicplayer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MusicPlayerActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.music_player);
        addListenerOnButton(null);
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton(View view) {
        ToggleButton artist = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.artistID);
        ToggleButton album = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.albumID);
        ToggleButton song = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.songID);

    }
}
```

music_player.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:background="#009ACD"
        android:text="Play All Music"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/toggleGroup"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/albumID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="addListenerOnButton" 
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/artistID"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/artistID"
        android:text="Album"
        android:textOff="Album"
        android:textOn="Album" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/songID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/albumID"
        android:onClick="addListenerOnButton" 
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/albumID"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/albumID"
        android:text="Song"
        android:textOff="Song"
        android:textOn="Song" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/artistID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="addListenerOnButton" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="63dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Artist"
        android:textOff="Artist"
        android:textOn="Artist" />
</RadioGroup>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please choose an "accepted answer" if one of the answers below helped you out. If not, please let us know the problems you are having

Answer (score 1):

Issue is Toggle Button isChecked Method is not getting fired.

**OPTION 1**

In your xml file, add this line for each of the toggle button

```
android:onClick="MethodName"
```

Example

```
<ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/albumID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/artistID"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/artistID"
        android:text="Album"
        android:textOff="Album"
        android:textOn="Album"
        android:onClick="onAlbumIDClicked" />
```

In your oncreate method, create respective methods and then check if they are checked or not. That would work.

**OPTION 2**

Remove all the If statements and Add this code below

```
        artist.setOnCheckedChangeListener(changeChecker);
        album.setOnCheckedChangeListener(changeChecker);
        song.setOnCheckedChangeListener(changeChecker);

        OnCheckedChangeListener changeChecker = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked){
            if (buttonView == artist) {
                artist.setChecked(true);
                album.setChecked(false);
                song.setChecked(false);
            }
            if (buttonView == album) {
                artist.setChecked(false);
                album.setChecked(true);
                song.setChecked(false);
            }
            if (buttonView == song) {
                artist.setChecked(false);
                album.setChecked(false);
                song.setChecked(true);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**OPTION 3** - Using Radio Group

in your xml file, add the below lines of code wrapping the 3 toggle buttons.

```
<RadioGroup android:id="@+id/toggleGroup"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
```

In your activity class, create a listener

```
static final RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener ToggleListener = new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(final RadioGroup radioGroup, final int i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < radioGroup.getChildCount(); j++) {
                final ToggleButton view = (ToggleButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(j);
                view.setChecked(view.getId() == i);
            }
        }
    };
```

Now, register the listener in OnCreate Method.

```
((RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.toggleGroup)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(ToggleListener);
```

Now in the onToggle Method, based on the id, set accordingly.

```
public void onToggle(View view) {
    ((RadioGroup)view.getParent()).check(view.getId());
    // app specific stuff ..
}
```

Comment: @VinceEmigh, Agreed. There are better ways of handling this. But i provided the fix for the issue he is facing in his code.

Comment: I updated my code. I added an onclick = the method's name, but it is giving me a nosuchmethodexception. Why doesn't it see my method "addListenerOnButton"?

Comment: @VinceEmigh, Added details of RadioGroup to my answer :)

Comment: Already created my own answer; didn't think you were gonna do it after seeing your 2nd option, although I see you have added it as the 3rd option. In my opinion, it should be listed as the first option, but thats just preference. As promised, +1. But now you gotta compete against my answer ;) (at least you get a +1 head start :D)

Answer (score 0):

You should instead be using a `RadioGroup` to manage de-selecting any other selected item after an item has been selected. It's called "*multiple-exclusion*", which ensures only 1 item is selected at a time.

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/toggleGroup"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/albumID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="addListenerOnButton" 
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/artistID"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/artistID"
        android:text="Album"
        android:textOff="Album"
        android:textOn="Album" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/songID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/albumID"
        android:onClick="addListenerOnButton" 
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/albumID"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/albumID"
        android:text="Song"
        android:textOff="Song"
        android:textOn="Song" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/artistID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="addListenerOnButton" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="63dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Artist"
        android:textOff="Artist"
        android:textOn="Artist" />
</RadioGroup>
```

This group will ensure only 1 `ToggleButton` is selected at a time.
Now, if you wanted to add listeners to this, you must specify the `onClick` attribute. For the value, you specify which method you want to execute.

The method must

- Be public
- Return void
- Define a View as its only parameter (this will be the View that was clicked)

The problem with your `addListenerOnButton` method is that it does not declare a `View` parameter. Your method should look like

```
public void addListenerOnButton(View view) {

}
```

Also, since you have the `RadioGroup`, you no longer need to manually deselect the other buttons.

Comment: I removed the manual deselects and updated my code above. But the problem is now if I click on one button and click another they both will be on. I have to turn off the button by clicking it again, which is what I don't want?

Comment: @gmanplex Android's `RadioGroup` is extremely similar to `ButtonGroup` (if you've ever used it). If two buttons are in the same group, they cannot both be selected at the same time. Right now, you're manually handling deselecting, because you have no system to manage that for you. That's what `RadioGroup` is for. It ensures only 1 button in the group is selected at a time